# Desktop doesn't lock when running Virtualbox

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, screen-lock

I am running Kali Linux as my host OS.  To keep this host installation clean, I run VirtualBox to host a guest instance of Linux Mint.  In the virtual machine is where I run a web browser, and install other applications that might unexpectedly "phone home" at an undesirable time.

If I leave the virtual machine running and with focus, the virtual Linux Mint machine's screen will lock after its timeout, but the host OS desktop never locks itself.  If I leave the virtual machine running, but use the mouse to put focus on a desktop app, the host desktop locks itself as expected.

I have tried configuring the host desktop to lock before the virtual desktop locks, and I have also tried configuring the virtual desktop to lock before the host desktop locks.  I get the same results either way - the host OS never locks.

My host OS of Kali is 4.12.0 (64-bit), and my version of VirtualBox is 5.1.26_Debian.

How do I configure the system to ensure the host desktop locks regardless of whether or not I'm running VirutalBox?